# Increased bundle size after upgrading to MUI v5 in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I updated MUI in my Gatsby project to v5, but the bundle size has increased by about 10 KB. I know it's not a tree-shaking problem.

I had to update Gatsby and React and a bunch of other packages in the process, but I think the increase in size is mainly because of MUI.

Here is an analysis of the build size before upgrading:

[image]

[image]

And here's after the upgrade:

[image]

[image]

Is this normal or is there a solution to reduce the size?

I'm using tss-react. You can see the exact versions that I'm using here:
https://github.com/SeyedAlirezaFatemi/seyedalirezafatemi.github.io/blob/feature/upgrade/package.json

Comment: it makes sense since mui5 comes with more components

Comment: You can try default importing and gzipping your bundle.